# How to store an ID in a database from 3 different tables

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I want to insert a product ID in my Product table.

ID should be like this form:

`Department_code-Sub_department_code-Product_code`.

For example, I want to input Chicken. It's department is Grocery  (01), Sub_Department is Meat  (03), Product_code is 05. The Product_ID would be `01-03-05`.

This ID will be used in different forms too.

So I want this ID to store in the Product table. How to solve this problem and what will be the datatype of the product ID?

Comment: Please take some time and clean up this post.  Its really hard to read right now.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Don't do this.  Make a surrogate key in your product table for this value, and use regular ID columns to relate to other tables.  Don't use this computed value as a real key.

Answer (score 2):

This type of key will be hard to maintain.
Try the following:

1. Use an identity column as an ID.
2. Add the Product ID as [Computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) composed of  `Department_code` `Sub_department_code` and `Product-Code` (and mark is as Unique if required).

Comment: This is the correct answer +1, but as @Joe said in the comments, dont do this.